# Error: Missing '}' or object member name. For Schema Job Posting

Tags: schema

When I test the code I keep seeing an error. even though I copied the code from Google WebDev website.
I tried removing some extra comma but the error keeps appearing on the test page

Here is my code. I am not able to find the issue.

```json
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "JobPosting",
        "title": "Varsity Squash Coach at Léman Manhattan Preparatory School",
        "description": "The responsibilities of the Head Coach include: 
    
    
    
    Organizing daily sessions taking attendance, communication with players and parents. 
    
    Proven ability to exemplify the highest standards of leadership, sportsmanship, and respect
    
    Excellent organizational skills and the ability to communicate effectively with all constituents
    
    Willingness and ability to work evenings as dictated by game schedule
    ",
        "identifier": {
            "@type": "PropertyValue",
            "name": "Léman Manhattan Preparatory School",
            "value": "SG183"
        },
        "datePosted": "2022-09-12",
        "validThrough": "2022-11-11",
        "employmentType": "TEMPORARY",
        "hiringOrganization": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Léman Manhattan Preparatory School",
            "sameAs": "https://www.lemanmanhattan.org/",
            "logo" : "https://v5.airtableusercontent.com/v1/7/7/1663804800000/NP8X2ipIaw46UWmRKjo34Q/f6dZOI2Z0GjagfFsHhf7KT28qq7EBvzKwvoSLV7XczwvLpCAjzo3yYYWQSJpeS8fx6jK89TlrnYRuJDBiHOv4g/l1QsKwP2dRMo_vZ_zqRZq8fUwCKJmHXDzgBTXkr5Iao"
        },
        "jobLocation": {
            “@type": "Place",
            "address": {
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "41 Broad St",
                "addressLocality": "New York",
                "addressRegion": "NY",
                "postalCode": "10004",
                "addressCountry": "USA"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a “typographic” quotation mark instead of a regular "typewriter" mark in `jobLocation.@type`. With syntax highlighting you can see that something is off starting at that line.

```json
"jobLocation": {
    "@type": "Place",
    ...
```